# TEXTJOIN no duplicates no blanks, table, seperate columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, textjoin, excel-tables

I have this table:
[image]

on Cell A4 i want the value "Orange". I want to take only the summary of the three Fruit columns marked in orange:

- table format (so instead of cells B2,E2,H2 I need [@Fruit 1], [@Fruit 2], [@Fruit 3])
- only the fruit columns which are separated by irrelevant price and weight columns between them.
- no duplicates (so Fruit 1: Apple & Fruit 2: Apple 2 becomes just "Apple" and not "Apple,Apple")
- no blanks (so Row 4 will be "Orange" and not "Orange,")

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to include the `textjoin` tag because that's what you're going to need to use.
Something like this:
`=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, [@Fruit 1], IF([@Fruit 1] = [@Fruit 2], "", [@Fruit 2]), IF(OR([@Fruit 1] = [@Fruit 3], [@Fruit 2] = [@Fruit 3]), "", [@Fruit 3]))`.

That second parameter in the `Textjoin` formula sets it to ignore empty values. The IF formulas return empty values if their value has shown in a previous column (that is, Fruit 2 checks Fruit 1, Fruit 3 checks both Fruit 1 and 2 columns).

Comment: Works! I appreciate the help Spencer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Excel365` then use below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Table1[@])&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')=.]")))
```

[image]

Comment: i do have Excel 365, it seems like Spencer Barnes' answer is more general and it works, i appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table is called `Tbl_Fruit`, in Cell `A2`, you can enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(INDEX(Tbl_Fruit[[Fruit 1]:[Fruit 3]],ROW()-1,{1;4;7})))
```

Alternatively, you can enter the following formula in `A2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(FILTER(Tbl_Fruit[[Fruit 1]:[Fruit 3]],LEFT(Tbl_Fruit[[#Headers],[Fruit 1]:[Fruit 3]],5)="Fruit"),ROW()-1))))
```